# programmatically intercept traffic originated by Android 3rd party libraries included in my app

Tags: android

I'm trying to write some code that intercepts any network traffic from/to my Android app, including traffic originated by 3rd party libraries, on a non-rooted devices. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: you can use VPN, like this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy.drony&hl=en

Comment: Any news? did you find a solution? thnx!

Comment: Were you able to do it?

Comment: Did you find the solution?